# Why is git rebase taking long

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Normally it takes a few seconds but this time it's been more than 30 minutes. I resolved some conflicts, then continued the rebase but it's not finishing. Should I cancel and try to continue the rebase again or wait it out? I am using sourcetree btw.

Comment: I'm not sure we can really tell you why. It could be many things.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by `not finishing`? What exact behavior are you seeing, what is happening right before it and what is the output? Can you paste the debug logs?

Comment: Are you sure that git did not opened an editor (or a new tab in an existing instance maybe also in background! ) and is waiting for you to validate the commit message, save and close the editor? A screen shot of Git terminal output or copy/paste would help to diagnose...

Comment: yeah so i was using sourcetree and it was just taking forever so i used the terminal and it worked fine. i guess it's an issue with sourcetree when you try to continue a rebase.

Answer (score -1):

yeah so i was using sourcetree and it was just taking forever so i used the terminal and it worked fine. i guess it's an issue with sourcetree when you try to continue a rebase it just goes on forever.